# How many slack variables need to be introduced?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming

So I was trying to solve this exercise (from DPV book)
[image]

I modeled the problem as such:
minimize : $4x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 + 3x_4 $ s.t:
$ x_1 + x_2 = 8 $  (Mexico's production)
$ x_3 + x_4 = 15 $ (Cansa's production)
$x_1 + x_3 \geq 10$ (delivered to New York , I am not sure about the enequality)
$ x_2 + x_4 \geq 13$ (delivered to Cal , again:  I am not sure about the enequality)

My problem is that if I follow this model then in order to convert the LP into standard form **I am going to introduce 2 slack variables**. But 2 slack variables are less than my number of equations $m = 4$ and my initial base will only have 2 variables meaning that **I will never be able to find the values of the 4 (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)** .
**If I try to remove the enequalities** (since I know how much product these towns consume I have no reason to deliver more) but then I have no slack variables and the system has a unique solution (or it is impossible) which would not make sense for an optimization problem .
**If I try to add enequalities in order to reach 4 slack variables** , it does not make conceptual sense to me . Will it be $\geq$ or $\leq$ for the production? I have no clue...

Can you help me identify what I am thinking wrong?
First of all, mathematically speaking in order this LP to be bounded and solvable I need 4 slack variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_{ij}$ the amount schnuppels of duckwheat which are delivered from location $i$ to location $j$, where $k,n,c,m$ denote the corresponding locations Kansas, New York, California and Mexico.  Kansas can deliver at most 15. Thus the tranportation constraints (supply) is $x_{kn}+x_{kc}\leq 15$. Similar for Mexico: $x_{mn}+x_{mc}\leq 8$. For both constraints you need a slack variable each to obtain equalities. For New York and California you have  demand constraints, thus at-least-constraints. I agree with your constraints.

$$x_{kn}+x_{mn}\geq 10, \quad x_{kc}+x_{mc}\geq 13$$.

For both constraints you need a surplus variable each and probably  artificial variables if you apply the simplex algorithm. I agree with your objective function as well.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints should be equalities, so you would have $x_1 + x_3 = 10$ and $x_2 + x_4 = 13$, with $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \geq 0$. They are equalities because we would never deliver more or less than they have demand for.

You mention that if there are no slack variables "the system has a unique solution (or it is impossible) which would not make sense for an optimization problem", however a generic linear program can have a unique solution.

Comment: I disagree with your equalities. There is no reason why California and New York cannot  receive more than their current demands. The goal is to minimize the transportation cost, not to deliver the exact demand quantities. Other aspects are not considered.

Comment: @callculus42 Sure they can, but in a practical modeling of it who would take this excess demand? Also The total supply available is 23 so the greater than or equal constraints would not make sense the highest they could be is 10 and 13 while still meeting demand for both if either is any higher the supply does not exist to fulfill it.